# NMSE of complex numbers

Tags: signal-analysis, math

Actually I am doing an RF measurement and this includes phase and power. i generate a list of powers ranging for example from (-50 to 40) dBm, while the phase rotate to make it for example spiral shape as shown in the attached graph. Then I measure that spiral.

I wanted to calculate the error between the measured and targeted signals.

The normalised mean square error (NMSE) has been suggested to be used. But This one shows me high error even when i see virtually a good agreement through the graph.

The Equations that I have used is shown below in the attached graph. is there better method to calculate such kind of error?

[image: spiral shape and the equations]

Comment: If there are multiple approaches that you can find,asking us will only give you ... yet another one. The point is that which formula is right for you is not defined by how you call it ("NMSE"), but what you need it for, and in which context you're moving. So, you need to explain all that in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: hey, you posted an edit to your question, only mistakenly as an "answer". Now you've (rightfully) deleted that "pseudo-answer", but you haven't edited your original post so far?

Comment: Sorry for that , I guess there was a problem when i used the phone app.

Comment: Don't apologize. Go and edit your question.

Comment: … OK. We will have to practice that one. Crucial info like this belongs *in the question*, not in a comment. Can you **edit** your question to include that info (it's not like I've asked you three times to edit your question already…)

Comment: @MarcusMüller hello, have you seen the modified question, actually I been waiting for your reply

Comment: Thank you for updating! This makes it much clearer. I don't have time right now to look at it, but I've upvoted it and I do think it will have a lot of visibility now.

Comment: Anybody wold help here, any suggestion ???